# Possible attacks using public key in a certificate

Tags: encryption, tls, cryptography, public-key-infrastructure, attacks

this is purely an exploratory question.
If this is not the right place to ask for it,
please point me to the right one.

TLS version: TLS 1.2
CIPHER SUITE : TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
(any cipher suite that involves creation of a pre-master secret)

**Note:** I understand in TLS 1.3 , the handshakes are encrypted after Server Hello.

If that is the case and in case of TLS 1.3 a middle man cannot get the public key's shared during the handshake then, only scenario, I am looking at is, when an attacker breaks in to a device and gets the certificates.

I am exploring PKI for TLS connections.
This is a scenario where the certs would be self signed and we are doing mTLS.
I understand the basic concept to be the following:

Server (S) :

- server SSL certificate.
- server private key.
- client CA's SSL certificate. (to be used in trust store for verification)

Client(C) :

- client SSL certificate
- client private key.
- Server CA's SSL certificate. (to be used in trust store for verification)

**As for as the handshake:**

**Verification:**

1. Server verification is done using the Server CA's certificate by the client.

(Public key of CA is used to obtain the has from the sign and then this has is compared to be identical and validated).

2. Client verification on the server is done using Client CA's certificate by the server.

***This is the only place where the public key of the respective CA's are used.***

**Encryption**

1. The client random is encrypted using the server's public key in the server's ssl certificate and sent to the server for decryption.

The server random is not encrypted and sent as plain text in Server hello.

Thus, the public keys involved i.e

1. Server's public Key,
2. Client's Public key
3. Client CA's public key,
4. Server CA's public key

are available only in the certificates (.i.e signed docs with public key and other meta info).

***So, with the above understanding,

I am looking understand the following:***

**Question 1.**

So, where exactly is the client's public key used?
Is the client's ssl certificate shared,
limited to only verification and has no contribution to key exchange and thus encryption?

**Question 2:**

Given that the client certificate and server's certificate are exposed in the handshake,
even though it cannot be used for getting useful data,
can the info in the certs (like CN,public key) be used to do DDoS kind of attacks?

(DDoS is the only one I can think of).

**Question 3:**
Given that the scenario addresses a self signed certificate,
if an attacker manages to get the CA's certificate on either the client/server,
can this be used to perform any kind of attacks?

When I say attacks I am not necessarily looking at a total compromise,
DDoS is kind of an example where data is not compromised ,
but the service is rendered unresponsive.

***But crux is , are there any attacks that can be done using the public keys alone?
Be it the public key of the CA's , Client public key, Server's Public Key***

If that is the case, can this be solved by:

1.sending an encrypted version of the certificate in the handshake such that no middle man can actually access it.
2. locking the CA certs inside HSM modules etc.

The motive behind this exploration is to understand any possible attacks using the public keys.
I somewhat feel, the idea where public key can be used to perform an attack is unwarranted, but I am not that aware of different possible attacks.

Comment: I am not sure if your question can be answered in its current form. There are multiple types of certificates respectively public key crypto systems (RSA ECDSA ...) as well as multiple TLS versions and cipher suites. The answer may be different for each combination of these variables. I would recommend you to specify which asymmetric crypto the key in the certs use, which TLS version and which cipher suite you use.

Comment: *"The client random is encrypted using the server's public key in the server's ssl certificate and sent to the server for decryption."* - No, that's wrong.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I am looking at 4) in this, possible that my understanding is wrong.
[https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.2?topic=tls-overview-ssltls-handshake]

Can you help me understand this better?

Comment: @AbhilashGopalakrishna: There is a difference between "random byte string" used as part as the RSA key exchange and the "client random" - the latter is part of the ClientHello. Apart from that RSA key exchange is obsolete anyway, so the description you refer to does not reflect modern use of TLS.

Comment: @Robert have updated the question with details and a note.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich got it,thanks,I will read up more on that part. Will edit the same, after obtaining some more clarity.

I am also looking at possible attacks that can be made using the public keys alone, how feasible it is/is such an attack even a distant possibilty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beware that there are a few mistakes in what you think you know. You've probably been reading misinformed or outright wrong simplifications. I'll address a few below, but I recommend reading some good references with an open mind. Good references include [TLS: every byte explained](https://tls.ulfheim.net) and [How does SSL/TLS work?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20803/how-does-ssl-tls-work).

> TLS version: TLS 1.2 CIPHER SUITE : TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (any cipher suite that involves creation of a pre-master secret)

Every cipher suite involves the creation of a pre-master secret apart from a few TLS ≤1.2 cipher suites that don't encrypt data (null cipher suites) and are very rarely used.

In terms of understanding a TLS handshake, the “mainstream” cipher suites are the ones that use a key agreement protocol to establish a one-time session key, and a signature mechanism to verify that the server is who it claims to be (and, with mutual TLS, also to verify that the client is who it claims to be). Those cipher suites have DHE or ECDHE in the name ((**e**lliptic-**c**urve) [**D**iffie-**H**ellman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange), **e**phemeral (= one-time)), as well as a signature method ([RSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)#Signing_messages), [DSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Signature_Algorithm), [ECDSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Signature_Algorithm), [EDDSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EdDSA)).

TLS ≤1.2 has various other mechanisms that I won't go into. I'll just mention RSA encryption (RSA without any kind of DH in the cipher suite name), which is somewhat popular in tutorials because it's a bit simpler to explain, but is deprecated [because it has security and performance downsides](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/256180/why-is-there-a-key-exchange-for-symetric-in-tls-needed). Forget about RSA-encryption cipher suites unless you have a specific need to understand them. They don't exist in TLS 1.3 any more. There are also PSK (**p**re-**s**hared **k**ey) cipher suites, even in TLS 1.3; these are only useful in special circumstances where the client and the server have a shared symmetric key, mostly for tiny embedded devices that don't have enough computing power for asymmetric cryptography, and, in TLS 1.3, for session resumption.

> Note: I understand in TLS 1.3 , the handshakes are encrypted after Server Hello.

> If that is the case and in case of TLS 1.3 a middle man cannot get the public key's shared during the handshake then, only scenario, I am looking at is, when an attacker breaks in to a device and gets the certificates.

Correct. However, this only matters for privacy: when you don't want attackers to know who is connecting to who. For the core security of the connection (preventing attackers from impersonating one side, or from knowing what data is exchanged), the public keys are considered public knowledge: any security analysis assumes that attackers already know the public keys.

> Server verification is done using the Server CA's certificate by the client.
> (Public key of CA is used to obtain the has from the sign and then this has is compared to be identical and validated).

This is correct with respect to the general flow of information, but not with respect to how the verification works. In the simple case where the server sends one certificate which is signed by a CA that the client trusts, what the client checks is:

- Is the certificate well-formed and does is have acceptable parameters?
- Is the server name in the certificate identical to the name that the client is trying to connect to?
- Is the signature in the certificate a correct signature made by the CA's private key?

Note that the signature verification process is not an equality comparison. Making a signature and verifying a signature are complementary processes. It would not be possible to verify a public-key signature by signing and comparing results, since the verifier does not have the private key, which is required to calculate the signature.

> Client verification on the server is done using Client CA's certificate by the server.
> This is the only place where the public key of the respective CA's are used.

Correct.

> The client random is encrypted using the server's public key in the server's ssl certificate and sent to the server for decryption.

No. The client random is sent in plain text. It's the very first message sent by the client and no key has been established apart from the server's key pair, so this would only work if the server was capable of decryption, but servers that are up to modern standards only have signature keys. The point of the client random and the server random is to avoid [replay attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replay_attack). There would be no point in keeping them secret.

---

> Question 1.
>
> So, where exactly is the client's public key used?
> Is the client's ssl certificate shared,
> limited to only verification and has no contribution to key exchange and thus encryption?

The client public key is only used to verify that the client is who it claims to be. Likewise, the server public key is only used to verify that the server is who it claims to be. The session keys (pre-master secret and derived symmetric keys) are derived from the Diffie-Hellman key exchange.

> Question 2:

> Given that the client certificate and server's certificate are exposed in the handshake,
> even though it cannot be used for getting useful data,
> can the info in the certs (like CN,public key) be used to do DDoS kind of attacks?

The certificates are assumed to be public, at least for security properties other than privacy, so they aren't an attack concern, DoS or otherwise.

Regarding privacy, anybody can obtain a server's certificate by initiating a TLS connection to the server. In TLS ≤1.2, if a client sends a certificate as soons as it connects, this is also transmitted in clear text. In TLS 1.3, the latter part of the handshake is encrypted, so the client's certificate is private.

Note that when a client contacts a server machine that hosts multiple sites, it sends the name of the server it wants in a TLS protocol message called [SNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication). In TLS ≤1.2, a passive observer can see this information. In TLS 1.3, the SNI can be encrypted (this protects at least against passive attacks, I'm not sure how good it is against active attacks).

> Question 3: Given that the scenario addresses a self signed certificate,
> if an attacker manages to get the CA's certificate on either the client/server,
> can this be used to perform any kind of attacks?

This is a strange question: if the certificate is *self-signed* then there is no CA.

Assuming there is a CA, no. In most realistic scenarios, the attacker already knows the CA's certificate anyway. Anybody can just connect to the server to find out which CA it used: that information is in the server's certificate. The client CA can be private in TLS 1.3, like the client certificate, but usually it's an organization CA which the attacker would have plenty of ways of obtaining anyway.

> But crux is , are there any attacks that can be done using the public keys alone? Be it the public key of the CA's , Client public key, Server's Public Key

As I explained above, the only such attacks are attacks on privacy.

> If that is the case, can this be solved by:

> 1.sending an encrypted version of the certificate in the handshake such that no middle man can actually access it.

TLS 1.3 indeed encrypts part of the handshake for privacy.

> 2. locking the CA certs inside HSM modules etc.

Putting certificates in an HSM has no security benefit. The main reason to put a certificate in an HSM is if the HSM holds the corresponding *private* key, because it's convenient to store certificate(s) for the private key close to the private key.

(Note that some software documentation confusingly uses “certificate” to mean a bundle containing both a private key and a certificate for that key. I strongly recommend not to use this terminology because it's hard to reason about security properties when the same word is used for public and private information.)

> I somewhat feel, the idea where public key can be used to perform an attack is unwarranted, but I am not that aware of different possible attacks.

The main attacks related to public keys are of a different type: sending a malformed public key or certificate or other message containing a public key, and hoping to trigger a bug in the software that processes this message. The quality of mainstream security-related software has improved to a point where such vulnerabilities are pretty rare. But they're still a possibility, especially on never-upgraded embedded devices (such as many network appliances).

Comment: Note #20803, although ursinely precise and comprehensive, is for 1.2 and does not cover the changes for 1.3. ulfheim DOES have a 1.3 version, which is of course significantly different.

Comment: quibble, _Is the signature in the certificate a correct signature made by the CA's public key?_ A correct sig comes from the *private* key.  The rest of your answer is lucid and on point, so this is why I'm assuming this was a "I know what I wanted to type" error.  Also: Spot on request, don't use "certificate" to mean the bundle. The _cert_ is the _cert_, tout effing court.

Answer (score 3):

> So, where exactly is the client's public key used?
> ... limited to only verification and has no contribution to key exchange and thus encryption?

With modern key exchanges both the clients and the servers certificate (and their public keys) are only used for authentication, not for key exchange. With the obsolete RSA key exchange the public key of the server was also involved in the key exchange, but the clients public key not.

> Is the client's ssl certificate shared,

For authentication to work the certificate with the public key has to be known and it is therefore transferred within the TLS handshake. This is true for both server and client certificate.

> can the info in the certs (like CN,public key) be used to do DDoS kind of attacks?

I can think of no attacks which specifically require the public key. As for other data contained in the certificate: they don't usually pose a danger. But of course one might include information in a certificate which then help with attacks, for example by including the name of a secret but vulnerable endpoint in the list of subject alternative names.

> Given that the scenario addresses a self signed certificate,
> if an attacker manages to get the CA's certificate on either the client/server,
> can this be used to perform any kind of attacks?

This is similar to the last point, i.e. by itself the certificate and its content poses no danger but might of course include information which the attacker can use to compromise systems.